# Bibliography in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

```
 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \include{chapter1}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{biblio}
 \end{document}
```

The bibliography does not appear in the table of contents, have you an idea please?

If I add this:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

the bibliography will appear as a chapter in my document!!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To get the bibliography to be listed in the ToC as an unnumbered sectional unit (chapter or section), use `tocbibind` *without* the `numbib` option:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
```

Another option would be to use the `etoolbox` package to patch `\thebibliography` to use `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry i want it a chapter in the TOC  but without mention in the bibliographie page: Chapter2: Bibliographie

Comment: @researcher please see my updated answer.

Comment: i have used the second solution because the first one appear the listoffigures and list of table in the TOC

Comment: @researcher you can use the `notlot`, `notlof` options; see my updated answer.

Comment: ok, i have tested the first solution, it works, thank you :)

Comment: I have a problem with the second solution when used together with `hyperref`: If I click on the bibliography entry in the ToC I jump to the first bibliography entry rather than to the title of the bibliography (as it should be)!? Can this be solved by changing your code?

Comment: I have now posted the issue raised in my previous comment in a separate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99746/16865

Comment: first method works like a charm

Answer (score 15):

A very easy way is to include following line before **after** writing bibliography, i.e., after the command `\bibliography` in standard LaTeX or after the command `\printbibliography` using the package *biblatex*.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

here is the original post:
[Insert bibliography into table of content](http://lookherefirst.wordpress.com/2008/10/05/add-the-bibliography-in-the-table-of-contents/)

For example, in standard LaTeX

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}%writing the bibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}%Including it as a chapter
\end{document}
```

Or with the package *biblatex*

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=plain]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\printbibliography%Writing the bibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}%Including it as a chapter
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's problematic - if at the chapter starts at the new page it will show bibliography as starting on previous page then it should.

Comment: Yes, i recognized this too. But do you know how it can be changed to the real value even with this function?

Comment: No. But Gonzalo's method with `\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}` worked.

Comment: Ok, than sorry for this, i just recognized it a week later and forgot i just posted this solution here. But thank you for the reminder, otherwise i would be wondering next time again about this .

Comment: Note that here, `Bibliography` can be replaced with whatever you like, e.g. `References`, `Works Cited`, `Orange Monkey List`. Of course, it usually makes sense for this text to be the same as the title that appears at the top of your bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

Placing the

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

immediately below the

```
\begin{thebibliography}
```

seems to work.

Comment: Welcome! This works if the bibliography is “hand made”, but in the case of this question it is produced with BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I didn't see the question was BibTeX-bound.

Comment: If it is after, the hyperlink works but the page number in the ToC is the last page of the bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

Can use following example on adding

- Bibliography
- List of Publications
- Brief Biodata

---

```
\include{chap5} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Main_thesis}

\input{lop.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Publications}
\input{biodata.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Brief Biodata of the Author}
```

Comment: This solution was already correctly covered in another answer. You are adding the toc entry at the wrong point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that *tocbibind* only includes the bibliography as section, which looks like it's part of the last chapter. So I found a solution which also works with *hyperref* :

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\bibliography{biblio}
```