# Don't have "tocbibind" package

Tags: bibliographies, packages, tocbibind

I use the MiKTeX and LaTeX at my university and I wanted to include my bibliography in the contents page so I found out about the `\usepackage{tocbibind}` bit, but when I try and compile the file, it says I need to download the [package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind) and when I try, it doesn't let me.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What exactly do you do when you "try" to download the package?

Comment: While technically it is not an answer to the question (why a package does not instal) this answer [bibliography in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71153/16895) offers an alternative solution  to the underlying problem.

Comment: Use the MiKTeX Package Manager to install this package. Start it via the start menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your university does not allow you to change the installed system. So you have two possibilities:

1. Ask the computing center of your university to install all packages, including `tocbibind`.
2. Create a local texmf directory (usually you can do it in your personal user space), install `tocbibind` there and tell MikTeX with `Refresh FNDB` that there are new packages. See question [create a local texmf tree in miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) for help to create a local texmf directory.