# How to write additional content into bbl file?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, bibliographies

How can I tell LaTeX to write additional content to `bbl` file?

Background of my question (see also MWE below): The page number for the bibliography displayed in the table of contents is correct if and only if `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` is placed at the beginning of the `thebibliography` environment. Hence, using `bibTeX` I need to write `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` into the `bbl` file. If I place it before `\begin{thebibliography}` the page number is *first page of bibliography - 1*, if I place it after `\end{thebibliography}` it is *last page of bibliography + 1* (which in the MWE would be correct but not in general).

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{thebibliography}{B}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibitem[B]{B}
A. Brown
\newblock {\em Mathematics}.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct approach to add a bibliography entry to the ToC is not to fiddle with the `.bbl` file, but a) to add `\addcontentsline{toc}{(sectioning level>}{Bibliography}` to the (class-dependend!) definition of the `thebibliography` environment or b) to load packages for this task, e.g., `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

See also [Bibliography in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71129/bibliography-in-table-of-contents); Gonzalo Medina's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71153/510) shows how to patch the `thebibliography` environment for the `book` class.

Comment: Apparently `tocbibind` is incompatible with `imakeidx`. In particular, including `tocbibind` results in the loss of `\indexprologue{abc}. Therefore I do no like including a package just for this purpose. One never knows what side effects new packages may possibly have ...

Comment: @lpdbw Use Gonzalo Medina's approach or try to load `imakeidx` *after* `tocbibind`.

Comment: Yes, loading `imakeidx` after `tocibind` works. I wonder whether there are other unwanted effects due to `tocibind` which I am still ignoring ... I also tried Gonzalo Medina's second approach (the one with redefining `\thebibliography`) ... a remaining issue in combination with hyperref, is that if I click on the ToC entry for the bibliography, I jump to the first bib entry but not (as it should be) to the title of the bibliography ... maybe I will make this a comment of Medina's answer.